# Problem compiling document

Tags: overleaf

When I logged in to Overleaf this morning I was not able to compile my documents. All of them just looked like this: [image].

How can I get back to "normal"?

Comment: which errors do you get (click on the red 3)?

Comment: It will not open, but they were also there when the compiler was "normal".

Comment: Overleaf-specific questions should be addressed to the Overleaf helpdesk. I hear there LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore such errors, they indicate a problem and even if you get a pdf the output can be wrong.  Ask the overleaf support for help.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question does not show the error messages and only shows some lines of code, but not a complete, but minimal example file, the answer addresses two problems seen in the code:

- `\input{report.sty}`

  - The file `report.sty` is a reserved file name for a report class of the old LaTeX2.09 format. It should *not* be used for private files to avoid unnecessary ambiguities.
  - Packages should be loaded with `\usepackage` in LaTeX. A package file `myprojectpackage.sty` is loaded with `\usepackage{myprojectpage}`. The package file can be versioned with `\ProvidesPackage{myprojectpackage}[2021/01/18 My macros for the project]`. Also, LaTeX provides `\makeatletter` for the package file and assures the the category code of `@` if again restored after the package is loaded.
- Macro `\contentsname` cannot be directly redefined if package `babel` is used. The package defines language dependent macros like `\captionsenglish` that contains the definition of the "name" macros for the different loaded languages. A user redefinition can be added via macro `\addto`:

  ```
    \addto{\captionsenglish}{%
      \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
    }
  ```

  Example file:

  ```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes}

    \addto{\captionsenglish}{%
      \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
    }

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \section{First Section}
    \end{document}
  ```

  > [image]